# What is the best practisce to use ionic push pop efficiently?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In ionic mobile app I always use . What is the best practice to use push/pop method?

```
this.navCtrl.push(SpecificPage)
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by best practice? Please specify your question.

Comment: I mean when to navigate with push and when to navigate with pop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `push` to navigate to another page (push another page onto the navigation stack) and `pop` to close the current page (pop the current page off the navigation stack). 
I'd suggest you to read [this guide](https://www.joshmorony.com/a-simple-guide-to-navigation-in-ionic-2/) to understand navigation in Ionic.